# How to prevent thinkbook 16 laptop from underclocking and staying at low temperature?

Tags: power-management, intel, cpu, temperature, cpufreq

Recently I have purchased Lenovo Thinkbook 16 G5+ IRH with Intel i7-13700H processor.

While I was stress testing CPU on AC, its frequency reached 4.0GHz for a short time and hit 90C, and then it underclocked to 2.5GHz at 60C with 25 watts power consumption for a long time.

Apparently 60C/25watts is not ideal and I expect it to stay at ~80C/55watts. I tried setting performance governor, changing BIOS setting to extreme performance, and ignoring BIOS PPC TPC limits with no luck. However, the scaling_max_freq parameter still shows 4800MHz.

I don't want to undervolt CPU and look forward to increasing temperature and power limit. Is there any chance that I can prevent CPU from underclocking and staying at low tempature?

Comment: Does the BIOS provide any overclocking options, as this is what "increasing temperature and power limit" means? If not, there isn't much to be done.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting and then running a thermal throttling daemon to prevent over-temperature? You might have become locked at lower CPU frequencies due to the high temperature event.

Comment: @mikewhatever Unfortunately, BIOS doesn’t provide any related options :(